# jquery multiple selects and text input how to update price?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have code as follows:

```
        <input type="hidden" id="a_grade_price" value="0.068">
        <input type="hidden" id="b_grade_price" value="0.020">
        <input type="hidden" id="c_grade_price" value="0.016">
        <input type="hidden" id="d_grade_price" value="0.012">
        <input type="hidden" id="processing_fee" value="0.25">

        <select id="article_level_1" class="form-control font-open-sans-light" name="article_level_1">
        <option value="A">Grade A</option>
        <option value="B">Grade B</option>
        <option value="C">Grade C</option>
        <option value="D">Grade D</option>
        </select>                                   
        <input type="text" class="form-control font-open-sans-light" id="word_count_1" name="word_count_1" value="{{ old('word_count_1') }}">

        <select id="article_level_2" class="form-control font-open-sans-light" name="article_level_2">
        <option value="A">Grade A</option>
        <option value="B">Grade B</option>
        <option value="C">Grade C</option>
        <option value="D">Grade D</option>
        </select>                                   
        <input type="text" class="form-control font-open-sans-light" id="word_count_2" name="word_count_2" value="{{ old('word_count_2') }}">

        <select id="article_level_3" class="form-control font-open-sans-light" name="article_level_3">
        <option value="A">Grade A</option>
        <option value="B">Grade B</option>
        <option value="C">Grade C</option>
        <option value="D">Grade D</option>
        </select>                                   
        <input type="text" class="form-control font-open-sans-light" id="word_count_3" name="word_count_3" value="{{ old('word_count_3') }}">
```

every time there is a change to any of the selects or word_count text inputs, i wantg to update the total price, which is stored in a div with id=current_price_too.  How would I go about doing this in jquery?

Comment: And how does you JS look like ?

Comment: When any of the selects [`change` event](https://api.jquery.com/change/) is triggered, inside the event handler get all the selects value and use them to determine the price from your hidden input fields which hold the prices, then with that data calculate the total and set the total as the [HTML contents](http://api.jquery.com/html/) of the div you want the total to be displayed in.

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Use `$(:input).on('input')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to handle the select change event similar to this:

```js
var prices = {
  "A": 0.068,
  "B": 0.020,
  "C": 0.016,
  "D": 0.012,
  "processing": 0.25
}
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var totalCost = prices.processing
  $('select').each(function(index) {
    totalCost += prices[$(this).val()]
  })
  $('#current_price_too').text(totalCost)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="a_grade_price" value="0.068">
<input type="hidden" id="b_grade_price" value="0.020">
<input type="hidden" id="c_grade_price" value="0.016">
<input type="hidden" id="d_grade_price" value="0.012">
<input type="hidden" id="processing_fee" value="0.25">

<select id="article_level_1" class="form-control font-open-sans-light" name="article_level_1">
  <option value="A">Grade A</option>
  <option value="B">Grade B</option>
  <option value="C">Grade C</option>
  <option value="D">Grade D</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control font-open-sans-light" id="word_count_1" name="word_count_1" value="{{ old('word_count_1') }}">

<select id="article_level_2" class="form-control font-open-sans-light" name="article_level_2">
  <option value="A">Grade A</option>
  <option value="B">Grade B</option>
  <option value="C">Grade C</option>
  <option value="D">Grade D</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control font-open-sans-light" id="word_count_2" name="word_count_2" value="{{ old('word_count_2') }}">

<select id="article_level_3" class="form-control font-open-sans-light" name="article_level_3">
  <option value="A">Grade A</option>
  <option value="B">Grade B</option>
  <option value="C">Grade C</option>
  <option value="D">Grade D</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control font-open-sans-light" id="word_count_3" name="word_count_3" value="{{ old('word_count_3') }}">

<div id="current_price_too"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Store total price in a var.
- [On change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) of select (`#select option:selected`) get the option value.
- Get the corresponding value from your hidden input fields 
  `var newVal = $("#"+selected_val.toLowerCase()+"_grade_price").val()`
- Add new price to total price
- Show it in desired div - `$("#current_price_too").text("The total price is: $"+total_price);`

Use your existing skills to put this all together in your code.